# clang does not infer template argument in variadic template function with varargs

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, variadic-templates, clang++

Consider the code:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class... Args, class T>
T method(std::tuple<Args...>, Args..., T, ...) {
   return T();
}

int main() {
    method(std::make_tuple<int, float, double>(1, 1.0f, 1.0),
        1, 1.0f, 1.0, 1);
}
```

`g++` since 4.9 has no problem with compiling it. `clang++` on the other hand provides an error:

```
main.cpp:9:5: error: no matching function for call to 'method'
    method(std::make_tuple<int, float, double>(1, 1.0f, 1.0),
    ^~~~~~
main.cpp:4:3: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
T method(std::tuple<Args...>, Args..., T, ...) {
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Which compiler is right?

Comment: As in my understanding, this is how it works: `Args...`  on the toplevel is not at the end of the parameter list, so it appears in a non-deduced context, which makes `Args...` be equivalent to a 0-sized parameter sublist during pattern-matching argument deduction. So, the subsequent `T` matches against `1` which appears after the tuple argument, and will be deduced to `int`. Later when the compiler substitutes into `Args...` the arguments `int,float,double`, the compile parameterlist is `tuple<...>,int,float,double,int`. This list needs to match the argument types..

Comment: it does in this case, by accident since the last `1`'s type is the same as the first `1`'s type (actually GCC doesn't seem to care.. it compiles also if the last `1` is `1.0`.. but interestingly `T` stays `int`). Perhaps clang gives up when the pack expansion of the three types into `Args...` shifts the `T` which was deduced as `int` away from its earlier deduction argument position, and reports that it couldn't deduce `T`.

Comment: Unfortunately, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1388 doesn't contain an example for your case. Perhaps it's worth a message to std-discussion.

Comment: If you drop the `...`, gcc doesn't compile it either.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb actually I was sure that the T should be inferred from the fifth parameter of the method... provide bad test though...

Comment: @Barry yes, didn't test it... :/

Comment: @W.F. actually, Clang also rejects a conforming test code, so Clang has some nonimplemented features in any case (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4350348b8080a730). So for clang, the reason is that it simply doesn't implement 1388 yet. And for GCC, I don't know what should happen according to the spec. Gut feeling says it should fail because `T` cannot be deduced sensibly.

Comment: Ah, we have a case like yours in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1399 . In essence the "never deduced" of 1388 means that it is also not deduced at other possibly deducible contexts. So in your `tuple<Args...>`, that will also not provide a type list for `Args`, so in an end result, your code will be ill-formed because `Args` will stay empty and won't match the provided `tuple<>` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is ill-formed. Both compilers correctly fail to compile:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class... Args, class T>
T method(std::tuple<Args...>, Args..., T) {
   return T();
}

int main() {
    method(std::make_tuple<int, float, double>(1, 1.0f, 1.0),
        1, 1.0f, 1.0, 1);
}
```

We do have, from [temp.deduct.call], emphasis mine:

> When a function parameter pack
>   appears in a non-deduced context (14.8.2.5), the type of that parameter pack is **never deduced**.

`Args...` appears in a non-deduced context because, from [temp.deduct.type]:

> The non-deduced contexts are: [...] A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*.

So by the exact wording of the standard, `Args...` shall not be deduced so you have to explicitly provide it - which in this case still isn't really possible to due `T`.

But in this case, `Args...` appears both in a deduced *and* non-deduced context - there should be nothing preventing `Args...` from being deduced from the `tuple` argument as `{int, float, double}` and then simply re-using that deducing for the variadic arguments, and then deducing `T` as `int` at the end.

*But* this proposed process would conflict with the typical deduction process where we handle each parameter/argument pair independently. In this case, deduction on `T` depends very much on deduction on `Args...` from the `tuple<>` parameter/argument pair.

If you simply flip the ordering:

```
template <class... Args, class T>
T method(std::tuple<Args...>, T, Args...) { ... }
```

then both compilers compile it.

I have no idea why gcc accepts the original example with varargs. That's clearly wrong.

Additionally, if you flip the template parameter specification so that you can specify `T` without requiring deduction, then clang accepts but gcc rejects:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
T method(std::tuple<Args...>, Args..., T) {
    return T();
}

int main() {
    method<int>(std::make_tuple<int>(1), 1, 1);
}
```

I'd expect this to be well-formed - `Args...` can be deduced and `T` doesn't have to be. So the wording on "never deduced" is questionable, in my opinion.

Comment: This is less refined answer, and more stream of consciousness rambling that sort of approaches one - but hopefully the idea behind it makes sense.

Comment: The flipped ordering is fine, because you don't have a template parameter pack in the middle of the function parameter list anymore. So the "never deduced" doesn't apply anymore since it not anymore appears in a non-deduced context.

Comment: @Johannes woops, that meant to be attached to the other example. That 2nd one *should* work, no?

Comment: I think the same rationale for rejecting the initial asker's code applies: The spec text (DR 1399) says that "Args" is "never deduced". It is not only a non-deduced context for ", Args..., ", but it renders Args completely non-deducible everywhere. That's how I read it, at least, and it makes sense with the examples of DR1399. It also says "parameter pack is never deduced", not "function parameter pack", thereby it applies to the "class ...Args", not merely the "Args...", I think.

Comment: @Johannes But the examples there don't have a case where a parameter pack can be deduced and non-deduced together, I think this (overly complicated) case wasn't considered.

Comment: they have: the last example has `Args...` at the end, where it can be deduced to `int,int`. The second line shows this nicely, where the `0` matches the middle `int`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb so clang bug on accepting that last one?

Comment: I think it is invalid, but I'm not completely sure, since I've not implemented it. Richard or Jason would know, I suspect :)